# Can we declare @properties in a common file

Tags: objective-c, properties, protocols, readonly

I have a requirement where i have few `readonly` properties in a protocol and adopting that protocol to two classes (say A & B) , since the properties are `readonly` ,I am redeclaring them in the `.m Files` of both of my classes (A & B) can i some how avoid this duplicate redeclaration of all the properties in both the classes?

Comment: What would be the advantage of doing that?  Any benefit in terms of fewer lines would be negated by increased complexity.

Comment: Yes, you can declare them in NSObject file. Then include the header file where you need to use these properties. You can do same for functions.

Comment: @Droppy, fewer lines decrease complexity not increases.

Comment: @WasimSafdar  Thanx for your replay, if I do that way , how would I access the variables? I cant access it A.Var  or B.var  rt?

Comment: As you are defining protocol, you can adopt that protocol in both classes. Even you access the variables in that protocol and change them in classes. Then you do not need to declare variables in classes.

Comment: @WasimSafdar No, fewer lines doesn't reduce complexity as you have to open yet another file to see what properties are declared and what attributes they have.

Comment: I always try to use fewer lines, my clients easily understand the code and it is easy to modify it.

Comment: You are missing the point.  You have fewer lines but more files and declarations scattered across multiple files.  That is increased complexity.

Comment: More files, easy to access the properties, references, functions, protocols, That is the standard way of coding.

Comment: So having the Objective-c implementation in multiple files is the standard way?  That is not true at all.

Comment: Yes, it is. I have experience of more than 3 years and worked with multiple clients. Nobody likes repetition and 5000 lines in 1 file. I think we need to quit discussion here. You do it own way, me own

Answer (score 0):

You can place the common property definitions into a header file and include it in the interface for each class.

**Common header:** common-props.h

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) SomeType *common1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) SomeType *common2;
@property (nonatomic, retain) SomeType *common3;
```

**Implementation:** A.m

```
@interface A ()

// Note: you have to use include, not import,
// to ensure the contents will be interpolated, no matter what.
#include "common-props.h"

@end

@implementation A

    // Stuff

@end
```

Repeat for class B.

This approach is not recommended.  By me, anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Create a class and declare your readonly properties in that class. Then create your classes A and B inheriting from the class.

So your `CommonClass.h` would look like this

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CommonClass : NSObject

@property (strong, readonly) <Type1> property1;
@property (strong, readonly) <Type2> property2;

@end
```

Now you can create your classes A and B inheriting from CommonClass

```
@interface A : CommonClass
 @interface B : CommonClass
```

Comment: That negates the benefit of declaring them in a protocol.